# PHP for writing javascript - run out of parenthesis options

Tags: php, jquery, parentheses

I have run out of parenthesis. I am using PHP to kick off some javascript and am using echo. The problem is that I cannot do this.

```
echo = '$("#test").html("<input type="text"/>")';
```

as you can see. The will not work with the parenthesis required around html() and the input type.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Marvellous

Comment: I didn't know there is only a limited number of parens on the planet ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: We're nearing peak-parentheses!

Comment: @Mchl: Oh no! Everyone grab as many as he can!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to escape the paren- *ahem*, **quotes** using the backslash `\`:

```
echo = '$("#test").html("<input type=\"text\"/>")';
```

<sub>*P.s: parenthesis = brackets. quotation marks = " & '*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your apostrophes.

Like:

```
echo = '$("#test").html("<input type=\"text\"/>")';
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try just refactoring your script a bit.
this isn't ideal anyway and I agree that generally this is a bad way to acheive the script, but this is the quick n dirty hack I'd do to fix it (a slash escape is better though IMO):

```
echo 'var test = $("#test"), inputType="text";';
echo 'test.html("<input type="+inputType+"/>");';
```

It will work but it's a terrible solution :)

Answer (score 0):

do not use PHP to kick off some javascript nor use echo.

just close PHP tag and then write JS as is

The code you provided makes no sense to me, so I cannot write an example. if you make it to whatever language rules I'd be able to produce some example code